# How do I dynamically insert a web part onto a page using Sharepoint Designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, xslt, data-view-web-part

I have a requirement to create a DVWP which queries a list of items: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc. I have a webpart that takes an input (i.e. "1.1") and does some cool stuff with it.

What I would like to do is to iterate through my list in the DVWP and place my webparts on the page, passing in the DVWP values ( 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ) so the webpart can do its cool stuff.

This must all be done "no-code" as we don't have permissions to write server-side code.

The algorithm would look something like this:

> 1. Query list for values
> 2. for each value (X)
> 3. insert WebPart A on page with (X) as a parameter
> 4. insert WebPart B on page with (X) as a parameter
> 5. next (X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution. I made a page that takes the sub-element as a query-string parameter. It then renders the web-parts that it needs. Then in the main page, in the XSLT, for each row I use an iframe while passing the sub-element as a query-string. I call the su-element page in the iframe.

So I am not trying to use webparts in the XSLT, but I AM using iframes, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Data View Web Parts are very good at filtering data from lists and translating the XML to client side code like HTML or Javascript. However, I don't think a web part is a good target output, because that is normally processed on the server side. Instead, I would look at connecting the DVWP to the other web parts on the page and providing the values from the one to the ohters.

**Reference**

- [Connect data in Web Parts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA010024105.aspx)

Comment: After pondering more, I realized that the main sticking point here is that there are a variable number of weparts that will be on the page. This is why I was using a DVWP and using the foreach. Is there another way to add a variable number of webparts to a page at runtime?

Comment: Not that I can think of off the top of my head. What kind of web part is it? Can it be done another way?